# Collapse Thumbnail Window in Embedding Signing Frame?

Tags: docusignapi

So here's my problem:

We're using the Embedded Signing method in an existing website. We have only one document, a single page form, that we want our customers to sign *on the site* to proceed any further in our application. The process itself works just fine from a signing perspective, but I'm having a display issue.

The document frame has a thumbnail window displayed on the right hand side. Since this is only a one page single document, the thumbnail serves no useful purpose. The window is collapsible, but I've been unable to figure out how to make it start in a collapsed state. I know it's *possible* because I've seen this in the API Certification Checklist hosted on the actual docusign.com site. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [New Signing Experience](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2F10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com%2FDocuSignSigningExperienceEnhancementsGuide.pdf&ei=fv5sVOSGLMOnyASGsIHICw&usg=AFQjCNHZL4rwQ6LREqiILJ5-lv3Dqi0ItQ&bvm=bv.80120444,d.aWw) that's being released to production Dec 5th?  The thumbnail section is minimized by default in the new UI.  The overall UI is simplified quite a bit.  You can switch your DEMO account to the New Signing Experiencing under Preferences -> Features -> Use DocuSign Winter ’15 Signing Experience Now.  After Dec 5th the same option should be available for Production.

Comment: I'm not using a template, I don't think that applies?

Comment: I'm not using templates either.  The New Signing Experience affects all instances of actually signing the documents for that account.  I've used both the Remote and Embedded scenarios with the new UI and they behave the same.

Comment: Page 5 of the linked document has a screenshot and says, "Note that the page thumbnail view, on the right side, is hidden by default, which is a change from the current signing experience"